# Определение первого символа

Tags: java

Есть код. В метод передается массив слов String. Задача кода - выстроить слова в таком ключе, чтобы последняя буква предыдущего слова совпадала с первой буквой следующего слова. 
На входе:

```
Редька Кокос Сидр Апельсин
```

На выходе:

```
Кокос Сидр Редька Апельсин
```

Первым словом берется слово, первая буква которого не имеет совпадений с последними буквами других слов. Проблема заключается в том, что при определении первой буквы слова, для первого слова из массива первый символ стоит под номером 1 (charAt(1)), а первые символы других слов под номером 0 (charAt(0)).

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();        
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String name=reader.readLine();
        reader.close();
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
        while (reader2.ready())
        {
            String str= reader2.readLine();
            String[] buf=str.split(" ");
            for (String e:buf)
            {
                array.add(e);
            }
        }
        reader2.close();
        String[] itog = new String[array.size()];
        for (int i=0;i<array.size();i++)
        {
            itog[i]=array.get(i);
            System.out.println(itog[i]);
        }

        StringBuilder result = getLine(itog);
       // System.out.println(result.toString());

    }

    public static StringBuilder getLine(String... words)
    {
        if (words==null)  return null;
        String firstWord="";

        for (int i=0;i<words.length-1;i++)
        {
            int count=0;
            for (int j=i+1;j<words.length;j++)
            {
                if (words[i].toLowerCase().charAt(1)==words[j].toLowerCase().charAt(words[j].length()-1))
                    count++;
                System.out.println(words[i].toLowerCase().charAt(1)+" "+words[j].toLowerCase().charAt(words[j].length()-1));
            }
           // if (count==0) {firstWord=words[i]; break;}
        }
        if (firstWord.equals("")) firstWord=words[0];
        System.out.println(firstWord);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Я передаю четыре слова в файле:

```
Редька Кокос Сидр Апельсин
```

Строку я сплитю по пробелу и заношу в массив строк, который передаю в метод. При обработке приведенного выше кода на выходе получаю:

```
Редька
Кокос
Сидр
Апельсин
р с
р р
р н
о р
о н
и н
```

То есть для первого слова из массива на позиции 1 находится первая буква слова (для Редьки это буква "р"), а для всех остальных слов на позиции 1 находятся вторые буквы ("о" для кокоса и т.д.). Почему так происходит (почему первые символы для всех слов не находятся на одной и той же позиции?).

Comment: ваш код явно отличается от того, что вы опубликовали. добавьте в вопрос [mcve]

Comment: "То есть для первого слова из массива на позиции 1 находится первая буква слова" - это говорит о том, что в первом слове у вас затесалась лишняя буква. Проверяйте.

Comment: @vp_arth проверял в нотепаде на наличие символов перед первой буквой первого слова - ничего нет.

Comment: почему в notepad? Что по этому поводу говорит дебаггер? Что возвращается по нулевому индексу?

Comment: @vp_arth в нотепаде просто отобразил исходный файл с учетом невидимых символов, думал, что могло что-то затесаться при копировании строки. Если выставляю на нулевой символ, символ первого слова отображается как "".

Comment: @MikhailVaysman не хотел постить полный код, т.к. он сугубо черновой. Если это поможет, то выложил то, что сейчас имею.

Comment: я в коде вижу, что вы берете символ на позиции 1, а не 0.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, я проверял, что будет если сменить позицию. При (1) получается выход, который я привел в вопросе. При (0) я получаю по первому слову просто значение "", по остальным словам - первую букву. Пример выхода с (0): ` с`
` р`
` н`
`к р`
`к н`
`с н`

Comment: то есть при 0 позиции для первого слова я имею - "", для остальных слов - первую букву. При позиции 1 для первого слова имею первую букву, для остальных - вторую букву.

Comment: значит у вас в этот метод приходит не правильный массив. проверяйте в отладчике входные данные.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman нашел ошибку. Настолько тупая, что просто ужс. Я файл, с которого считывал строку, перекодировал в UTF-8 с BOM (о котором до сего момента не знал), в итоге в начале файла ставился символ \ufeff, он то мне все и портил